# How to tell CMake to pass no duplicate libraries in the link command

Tags: c, cmake, linker, iar, ninja

I have a circular dependency between the two static libraries `libA` and `libB`:

```
add_library(LibA STATIC a.c)
add_library(LibB STATIC b.c)

# Circular dependency: LibA <-> LibB
target_link_libraries(LibA PRIVATE LibB)
target_link_libraries(LibB PRIVATE LibA)

add_executable(Example main.c)
target_link_libraries(Example PRIVATE LibA LibB)
```

When generating the build configuration CMake tries to resolve these dependencies by passing `LibA` and `LibB` twice each to the linker:

```
ilinkarm.exe --silent CMakeFiles\Example.dir\main.c.o  LibA.lib  LibB.lib  LibA.lib  LibB.lib -o Example.exe
```

However the IAR linker I use already does multiple passes through the list of libraries and it would be sufficient if `LibA` and `LibB` are only listed once. Linking with the duplications does still work, but I get the following warnings:

```
[build] Warning[Li065]: duplicate file: "LibA.lib"
[build] Warning[Li065]: duplicate file: "LibB.lib"
```

**Is there a possibility to tell CMake that every library in the linker command has to be unique even with circular dependencies?**

I tried setting `CMAKE_C_LINK_EXECUTABLE` but I couldn't find an alternative to `<LINK_LIBRARIES>` which already seems to contain the duplicates. That's why this line results in the same warning:

```
set(CMAKE_C_LINK_EXECUTABLE "<CMAKE_LINKER> <OBJECTS> <LINK_FLAGS> <LINK_LIBRARIES> -o <TARGET>")
```

CMake version: 3.26.3
Ninja version: 1.10.2
IAR version: 9.32.2

Comment: What would be the outcome if you remove `target_link_libraries(LibA PRIVATE LibB)` and `target_link_libraries(LibB PRIVATE LibA)`? In my experience, __ilinkarm__ is not used to "link a library against each other".

Comment: To keep the example as simple as possible I omitted `target_include_directories` for `LibA` and `LibB`. If `target_link_libraries` would be removed, CMake can't resolve the includes between the two libraries and the build fails. `ilinkarm` is only used in the final step to link the executable, at which point CMake adds the duplications.

Answer (score 2):

Normally this is controlled by the [`LINK_INTERFACE_MULTIPLICITY`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/LINK_INTERFACE_MULTIPLICITY.html) property. However, CMake does not respect values of this property below `2`, so this cannot be done as of CMake 3.26. See the code here:

https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/d9641980d2a223e0a6fe42ff23499e55f49fd6d5/Source/cmComputeLinkDepends.cxx#L1314-L1328

```
size_t cmComputeLinkDepends::ComputeComponentCount(NodeList const& nl)
{
  size_t count = 2;
  for (size_t ni : nl) {
    if (cmGeneratorTarget const* target = this->EntryList[ni].Target) {
      if (cmLinkInterface const* iface =
            target->GetLinkInterface(this->Config, this->Target)) {
        if (iface->Multiplicity > count) {
          count = iface->Multiplicity;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return count;
}
```

Here is a link to the CMake issue tracker: https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues

Comment: From my understanding, the property `LINK_INTERFACE_MULTIPLICITY` is for **projects** which are faced with a compiler bug when build a very **specific** libraries or executables. The fact that the linker accepts only unique libraries should be expressed in a **toolchain/platform** file. Because that file is parsed before a project creates a library target, then toolchain/platform file shouldn't set target properties, but should set some *variables* (normal or CACHE).

Comment: @AlexReinking Thank you for your answer! Though it is unfortunate to hear that CMake doesn't support this at the moment...